# VS2012: How to change color of vertical bar left of text editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2012 there is a vertical bar next to the text editor, in which the red markers of breakpoints are shown:

[image]

Is there any way to set the color of this bar?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For the records, I have found the solution. You can change this setting under:

Tools ->
Options ->
Environment ->
Fonts and Colors ->
Text Editor settings ->
"Indicator Margin" (Item Background)

Comment: Many thanks! That is also what remains "broken" after importing colors e. g. off http://studiostyl.es/ .

Comment: In VS2017 this setting is under `Fonts&Colors/Printer and Cut&Copy/Indicator Margin`

Comment: In VS2019 this setting seems to be in the same place as the original answer above.