# Visual Studio 2017 dark theme has a white section I need to get rid of

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 where I imported a nice dark theme from https://studiostyl.es but unfortunately I am getting this white bar (see on the picture) on the left which I would like to make dark too. Which Visual Studio settings I should use to change the color of this particular bar UI section? 
Thanks, N -

[image: click to see the picture of Visual Studio UI with the white section]

Comment: I don't think that's by default like this. try to do a reset or re-install vs. do you have any add ins installed? maybe it's from an addin.

Comment: Hi. Got about 10 addins but this highly unlikely to be the problem. Before importing the theme I used VS default dark theme and the bar was black, so I am guessing it's the new them settings that overlooked the bar section. I have to further change the color manually now. Somehow...

Comment: It might help your readers if you updated your post to indicate _which_ theme you are using.  It would certainly help people interested in attempting to reproduce your problem.  See [ask] for more tips on asking effective questions

Comment: From the white bar's position above the left side of the zoom-level text box I'd _guess_ that the bar is the Indicator Margin.  There are a couple of ways you could test my theory.  You could insert a Breakpoint - if the red spot appears inside the white bar, the bar is the indicator margin.  You could go to **Tools | Options | Text Editor | General** and uncheck the **Indicator Margins** checkbox.  If the white bar vanishes, the bar is the indicator margin

Comment: Frank. Yes you are absolutely right, it is an indicator margin and I already found an answer to my question on SO.  Thank you very much for your help. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212988/vs2012-how-to-change-color-of-vertical-bar-left-of-text-editor